# How do I force SVG-supporting browsers to load the SVG instead of fallbacks?

Tags: html, svg, responsive-images

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="icons/home.svg">
  <img src="home-1x.png" srcset="home-2x.png 2x" alt="Home">
</picture>
```

Safari 9, which is perfectly capable of SVG loads home-2x.png instead on my retina MacBook. Why isn't it loading the SVG? How can I force its hand?

Thanks!

Comment: For testing purposes, try: `<source type="image/svg+xml" srcset="icons/home.svg 1x, icons/home.svg 2x">`

Comment: Also, are there browsers that support the picture element, that don't support SVG?

Comment: According to http://caniuse.com/picture, Safari 9.1 added picture element support, so also check what exact version you are using.

Comment: 9.0.1, sheesh. So, how about when someone browses the site using a browser that supports SVG but not PICTURE? What's the solution here to serve the PNG only as a fallback?

Comment: Using an `img` tag, the options aren't so great. I suppose you could do `<img src="home-1x.png" srcset="icons/home.svg 1x" alt="Home">` and get better support than picture. Still not full support for all browsers that support SVG though.

Comment: So are there better options some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was pointed out in a comment, `<img src="home-1x.png" srcset="icons/home.svg 1x" alt="Home">` works (for SVG; not in general).

If you want to support pre-srcset browsers, you can use

```
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="icons/home.svg">
 <img src="home-1x.png" alt="Home">
</object>
```

But this has some issues, too: both resources will be loaded, the `object` acts more like an `iframe` than like an `img` (you can select text in the SVG, it can execute scripts, navigate, etc).

Another classic is using `onerror` like this:

```
<img src="icons/home.svg" onerror="this.onerror=null; this.src='home-1x.png';" alt="Home">
```

This has the drawback that non-SVG browsers will unnecessarily load the SVG, and users without scripting and without SVG support will not load any image. I suppose that's not much of a problem.

Finally, you can use the `picture` markup and pull in http://scottjehl.github.io/picturefill/ and then it should just work (for users with scripting enabled).